# Google Tag Manager Image Tracking Pixel

Tags: google-tag-manager

With Google Tag Manager, is there a way to implement an image pixel on all pages?

I was sent the following:

```
<img src="http://<trackingpixel> />
```

Do I create a new Custom Image Tag or just use a Custom HTML Tag?

Comment: I've only seen this done as custom HTML (not to say that you can't do it in a custom image tag):

<img style="display:none" src="//blah/blah/blah">

Comment: After a bit more digging around, I believe you could use a custom image tag with the "Image URL" field containing the value of the "src" in your image tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the custom image tag and use the All pages rule to fire on all pages.